# R caret: Combine rfe() and train()

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I want to combine recursive feature elimination with `rfe()` and tuning together with model selection with `trainControl()` using the method `rf` (random forest). Instead of the standard summary statistic I would like to have the MAPE (mean absolute percentage error). Therefore I tried the following code using the `ChickWeight` data set:

```
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
library(MLmetrics)

# Compute MAPE instead of other metrics
mape <- function(data, lev = NULL, model = NULL){
  mape <- MAPE(y_pred = data$pred, y_true = data$obs)
  c(MAPE = mape)
}

# specify trainControl
trc <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3, search="grid", savePred =T,
                    summaryFunction = mape)
# set up grid
tunegrid <- expand.grid(.mtry=c(1:3))

# specify rfeControl
rfec <- rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, method="cv", number=10, saveDetails = TRUE)

set.seed(42)
results <- rfe(weight ~ Time + Chick + Diet, 
           sizes=c(1:3), # number of predictors from which should algorithm chose the best predictor
           data = ChickWeight, 
           method="rf",
           ntree = 250, 
           metric= "RMSE", 
           tuneGrid=tunegrid,
           rfeControl=rfec,
           trControl = trc)
```

The code runs without errors. But where do I find the MAPE, which I defined as a `summaryFunction` in `trainControl`? Is `trainControl`executed or ignored?

How could I rewrite the code in order to do recursive feature elimination with `rfe` and then tune the hyperparameter `mtry` using `trainControl` within `rfe` and at the same time compute an additional error measure (MAPE)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trainControl` is ignored, as its description

> Control the computational nuances of the **train function**

would suggest. To use MAPE, you want

```
rfec$functions$summary <- mape
```

Then

```
rfe(weight ~ Time + Chick + Diet, 
    sizes = c(1:3),
    data = ChickWeight, 
    method ="rf",
    ntree = 250, 
    metric = "MAPE", # Modified
    maximize = FALSE, # Modified
    rfeControl = rfec)
#
# Recursive feature selection
#
# Outer resampling method: Cross-Validated (10 fold) 
#
# Resampling performance over subset size:
#
#  Variables   MAPE  MAPESD Selected
#          1 0.1903 0.03190         
#          2 0.1029 0.01727        *
#          3 0.1326 0.02136         
#         53 0.1303 0.02041         
#
# The top 2 variables (out of 2):
#    Time, Chick.L
```

Comment: If trainControl is ignored by the rfe() function then consider removing trControl = trc and also tuneGrid = tunegrid.  Removing these settings won't change the results above.